# How to add Row from JTextField into JTable with Custom Table Model?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

This is my table model:

```
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return SetListTransaksiPenjualan.get(rowIndex).getDates();
        case 1:
            return SetListTransaksiPenjualan.get(rowIndex).getName();
        case 2:
            return SetListTransaksiPenjualan.get(rowIndex).getHobby();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

public String getColumnName(int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return "Date";
            case 1:
                return "Name";
            case 2:
                return "Hobby";
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) Post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/). 2) read [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for `JTable`. 3) Use `DefaultTableModel`.

Comment: @alex2410 So, I can't use AbstractTableModel? Can you show me some example with DefaultTableModel?

Comment: You can, but in that case you need to do all by yourself. See link in my first comment it has example. Or search using of table model at so, here is a lot of exxamples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create and add a DefaultTableModel like:

```
DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel(data,header);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Here data is double vector and header is single vector.

```
data = get(field);
Object[] d={data.get(i).get(0),data.get(i).get(1),data.get(i).get(2)};
model.addRow(d);
```

//Get data from database

```
get(field){
//Your Database connection
//Get data into vector
//return vector
}
```

Comment: how to add without database connection? So, I can add row dynamically

Comment: String field1=yourValue; String field2=anotherValue; Object[] d={field1,field2,...};  model.addRow(d);